# Validate multiple select inputs as a group - Parsley

Tags: jquery, plugins, parsley.js

I currently have three individual select boxes that gather a users date of birth. The fields are for the day, month and year and I'm using the [Parsley validation plugin](http://parsleyjs.org/) to validate each input individually.

However, I'm looking to find a way to validate all three inputs as a group instead. So instead of the validation displaying three validation messages on form error, it displays just one.

How possible is this to achieve using Parsley? Does anyone have any tips or tricks?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's possible to hack something up, there is currently no good & easy way to do this. See discussions in [this issue](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues/839).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Shame there's nothing native!